# Does Hibernate Optimistic Locking not work across different JVMs?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, optimistic-locking

We are using Optimistic Locking with JPA and it seems to work perfectly within each multi-threaded service no matter how many threads we add, but when two services running as separate apps are updating the same columns in a table they overwrite each other (dirty reads). Is Hibernate optimistic locking not guaranteed to work across separate JVMs? I've had a hard time finding any info on this.

We are using JPA with hibernate under the hood. Optimistic locking is working, at least between the threads inside each service, I can see it tripping exceptions and trying in the retry listener i added.

Here is some code

```
@Transactional
@Retryable(value = {Exception.class}, maxAttemptsExpression  = "${locking.max.retry.count:30}",
        backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "${locking.retry.sleep.time:10}"),
                listeners = "accountUpdateRetryListener")
public void balancesAndAmtsUpdate(TransactionSet transactionSet) {

       // new entity versions are picked up in here
        mapTransactionsToAccounts(transactionSet);
        groupAccounts(transactionSet);

        // update Accounts
        transactionSet.getAccountPostingAggregators().forEach( agg -> accountUpdate(agg, transactionSet));

        transactionSet.getNettingAggregators().forEach( agg -> {
            if (transactionSet.getDigestForPosting()) {
                accountNetTotalsUpdate(agg);
            }
            accountsNetSourceUpdate(transactionSet, agg);
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you use as version? Show us some code :)

Comment: Optimistic locking works at at the database level, so it is the same across multiple VMs as it is in multiple processes in a single VM. It is simple- it just checks that the version of the data in the DB matches what is expected in the update/delete statement. It is up to the application to ensure though that the versions in the entities are being respected, and you aren't doing something like serializing data around and merging it into the latest entity read from the database yourself - if you do, you'll want to check the version number yourself too.

Comment: We are using JPA with hibernate under the hood. @m02ph3u5. Optimistic locking is working, at least between the threads inside each service, I can see it tripping exceptions and trying in the retry listener i added.

I added some code to the question up top.

Comment: @Chris What do you mean by it works at the database level? Isn't optimistic locking an application-level concurrency control? Don't we need the first level cache to guarantee session-level repeatable reads?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 for version we have a column in the database tables where we want locking. This is updated automatically by JPA hibernate whenever there is an update to the record.

Comment: No, it has no requirements on caching. It is at the DB level because the DB updates the row or doesn't with the application using a clause that includes the ID for the row as well as the locking field value. ie where id = X and version=Y. Nothing is updated and an exception occurs if the version isn't still set to Y. This works for applications because the version field is passed around, and when that data is merged in, can't overwrite the data if the version field is at Y+N. Your other application might be incrementing the version or just not passing it around